# Select specific data from date field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get some  record from table for specific month and year and I have only complete date field.

[image]

In the above image I want to select the data from date but only for (2015-09)

E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE date = (year-month)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your date range from the beginning and end of that month.

```
SELECT *
    FROM attendance
    WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-09-30'
```

Comment: This one can utilize index on `date`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `year` and `month` function:

```
SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE year(`date`) = '2015' and month(`date`) = '9'
```

Comment: This one is good. But one problem is that if you want to use index you cannot :(

Comment: @1000111 Great!!! You can always catch some constructive point. Use index, maybe Kael's answer is better. :-D

Comment: Yes. @KaeL's answer can utilize index on `date` field.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `DATE_FORMAT`.
Your query is:

`SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') = '2016-05'`

Comment: Please put some data in place of `(year-month)` like `SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')='2015-09'`. Otherwise it seems confusing.